# How is PRESS related to SSE?

Tags: cross-validation

I was wondering how PRESS can be expressed in terms of SSE? I have been trying to prove the relationship, and found from one author that PRESS = nMSE but I can't understand why. Can somebody help, please?

Comment: What is PRESS, SSE and nMSE?

Comment: PRESS is predicted sum of squares. It is calculated by deleting one observation, fitting the model, then predict the value of the deleted observation using the model. SSE is the sum of residuals from a regression model